# Moving snapshots to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

***My requirement :***

Daily creation of snapshots which have to be stored in S3, which then, would be moved to Glacier after 7 days.

***This is what I have done*** :

I have three virtual machines in AWS. I have written a lambda function which creates a snapshot of each VM daily. Now, I got a requirement that the snapshots should be in S3 only for the first 7 days after their creation. After that, they have to be automatically moved to Glacier, where they will remain for a maximum period of 90 days. After that, they will get deleted from Glacier. I know that I have to apply lifecycle policies as per my requirement.

I have read in the documentation that snapshots are automatically stored in S3 but a user can't view them.

So, how can I apply the lifecycle policies to something that is not visible? Or is there any alternative to it?

Comment: You can't apply lifecycle policies to EBS snapshots since you don't own the  S3 bucket they reside in. Your requirements don't match the capabilities provided by AWS.

Comment: Ok. All the snapshots created are listed in the snapshots section of EC2. Can I now move these snapshots to an S3 bucket and then apply lifecycle policies? Or, can I do anything from the command line.

Comment: No, that's part of what I was implying earlier, that capability is not provided by AWS. You can't move snapshots to your own S3 bucket.

Comment: They tell you that snapshots are stored in S3 to give you an understanding of the reliability of the backup. That's it.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you again... Can we do it programatically through Lambda or from the CLI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128183/discussion-between-prudhvi-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to [Amazon EBS Snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html), then there are **no lifecycle capabilities available**.

Amazon EBS Snapshots are stored in the Amazon S3 infrastructure, but they are visible only as Snapshots within the Amazon EC2 console. The Snapshots can only be **moved** to different regions or **converted** into a New Volume. The cannot be downloaded or moved to other storage types/services.

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Backup](https://aws.amazon.com/backup/) service will help you achieve your goal.

> AWS Backup is a fully managed backup service that makes it easy to
>   centralize and automate the back up of data across AWS services in the
>   cloud as well as on premises using the AWS Storage Gateway. Using AWS
>   Backup, you can centrally configure backup policies and monitor backup
>   activity for AWS resources, such as Amazon EBS volumes, Amazon RDS
>   databases, Amazon DynamoDB tables, Amazon EFS file systems, and AWS
>   Storage Gateway volumes.